# Zend Instance is lost at random moments

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db

I have a website which runs on zend and recently it has stated losing the session variables when logged in `$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();` seems not to work at times any leads on what could be the issue

Comment: It's zf1 and it's EOL is Sep 8, 2016. So if it worked before it have to be work now except if you changed your code. Did you check if server changed recently? Maybe php's session timeout value changed in php.ini ?

Comment: @MehmetSÖĞÜNMEZ thanks . the session works above script works sometimes am wondering why it fails sometimes especially when the cookies are cleared

Comment: Clearing cookies will delete the session cookie, so you should expect to be logged out then (is that what you mean?) You should check the date & time on the server to make sure it's correct.

Comment: @TimFountain this happens when i log in the account the first time after clearing the cookie. then it happens randomly from there

Comment: Do you consistently access your site using the same domain name (for example, consistently with or without a www prefix)? Cookies set on the domain `www.example.com` should not expect to be sent for a request to the domain `example.com`?